reactで作成したアプリケーションをアップルストアを介さずに直接iPhoneにインストールすることは可能ですか？
reactを勉強中ですが、アップルストアを介さずに直接iPhoneにアプリケーションをインストールしたいのですが、何か方法はありますか？

ここでの React とは React Native のことでしょうか。もしそうであればタグを付け替えたいので質問です。

PWA(Progressive Web App) で実現できるのではないでしょうか？
以下のサイトは、PWA として開発されています。

https://www.pwastats.com/

iPhone であれば、サイトを開いて、[共有ボタン] - [ホーム画面に追加] を選択してインストールできます。
通常の Web サイトでも同様のことができますが、見た目の違いとしては、PWA では、URL 部分が表示されません。
create-react-app のオプションで、PWA のテンプレートが選択できるので、確認してみてください。
npx create-react-app <アプリ名> --template cra-template-pwa

TypeScript の場合は以下
npx create-react-app <アプリ名> --template cra-template-pwa-typescript

以下のサイトを参考にしてください。

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/

